# How do I call Oracle stored procedure from .NET 6 application deployed in Azure Web App?

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0, oracleclient

I have an application developed in .NET 6, which is calling few Oracle stored procedures. It was working fine when it was deployed on IIS on an on-premise server, because we were able to install Oracle Client on server easily and set the values for TNS.

Now issue arises after Azure Web App deployment. I don't know how to install Oracle Client in Azure Web app and set the values for TNS.

Also, if there are any other way around kindly suggest. Need your expertise to solve this issue.

Thanks